# How add the reference to JSOG.js (nativescript and angular2)?

Tags: android, angular, nativescript, jsog

I am trying manipulate JSON objects in a android project using NativeScript and Angular2, but, I can't add the reference to JSOG.js.

First, I run the command `npm install jsog --save`in prompt (Windows). Then, I put reference in file. I tried put the path in many ways, but, the error is "**Cannot find modules**".

File home.ts

```
import jsog = require("./../../node_modules/jsog/lib/JSOG.js");
```

[Path to JSOG.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIJ1x.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you use SystemJS, you could try something like that:

```
System.import('./../../node_modules/jsog/lib/JSOG.js').then(loadedScript=> {
  loadedScript.someMethod();
}
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Thanks, Thierry. That's similar to the problem I ran into when trying to dynamically load JSOG.js in this project. I can't import SystemJS to the project after install by npm. I will continue searching by answer.

Answer (score 1):

In order to import JSOG.js, you will a **d.ts** file for it. You can write it yourself or try to find it from somewhere else.

Another thing that you can do is to import it in the following way:

```
var jsog = require("jsog");
```

Then you can use it as object. The drawback is that there won't be any intellisense.